# Split a list into chunks of varying length

Tags: python, list, iterator

Given a sequence of items and another sequence of chunk lengths, how can I split the sequence into chunks of the required lengths?

```
a = range(10)
l = [3, 5, 2]
split_lengths(a, l) == [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

Ideally a solution would work with both `a` and `l` as general iterables, not just on lists.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) on an iterator of the list.

```
In [12]: a = range(10)

In [13]: b = iter(a)

In [14]: from itertools import islice

In [15]: l = [3, 5, 2]

In [16]: [list(islice(b, x)) for x in l]
Out[16]: [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

or :

```
In [17]: b = iter(a)

In [18]: [[next(b) for _ in range(x)] for x in l]
Out[18]: [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def split_lengths(a,l):
    resultList = []
    index=0

    for length in l:
        resultList.append(a[index : index + length])
        index = index + length

    retun resultList
```